# If power series in two variables and logarithmically convex Reinhardt domains

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, convex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I have a power series $\displaystyle\sum_{m,n\geq0}c_{mn}x^my^n$, and I know that it converges absolutely on the upper triangle $\mathcal{T}=\{(x,y):0\leq x\leq y\leq1\}$.

I know that the domain of absolute convergence of a power series in several (real or complex) is a logarithmically convex Reinhardt domain but I am having difficulty seeing the application of that fact in this context.

My question is: What region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is guaranteed to be contained in the domain of absolute convergence for the series, given that that domain contains the triangle $\mathcal{T}$?

Comment: I now see that since the series converges absolutely at $(1,1)$, the series will converge absolutely on the entire square $\{(x,y):|x|,|y|\leq1\}$.  So the question is whether the domain of absolute convergence must be any larger than that.

Comment: A Reinhardt domain is an idea from several complex variables, yet your example is in several real variables. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{x^n}{n^2} + \frac{y^n}{n^2}\right ).$$